# Heroku Post Deployment (

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku-postgres

My question regarding to rails crashing post deployment. My deployment works fine. I created a standard rails app with `rails new myapp --database=postgresql`. Then, I commit my changes and push to heroku. Which tells me:

```
git push
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 25, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 1.94 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.9)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.8.2)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
       Using activesupport (4.0.2)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.2)
       Using mime-types (1.25.1)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.2)
       Using activemodel (4.0.2)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.1)
       Using activerecord (4.0.2)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.2)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.2)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.3)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using json (1.8.1)
       Using pg (0.17.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.10.1)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
       Using rails (4.0.2)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using sass (3.2.12)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
       Using sdoc (0.3.20)
       Using turbolinks (2.0.0)
       Using uglifier (2.3.3)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (0.46s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (1.92s)
       Cleaning assets
-----> WARNINGS:
       Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.

   You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
   To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
   ruby '2.0.0'
   # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 21.3MB
-----> Launching... done, v10
   http://communityshare-web.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:communityshare-web.git
   1488048..2268228  master -> master
```

So it looks like everything went ok, but I get an error page when I visit my heroku app.

After running `heroku logs`, I see the following:

```
2013-12-12T21:56:18.114338+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-12-12T21:56:25.558687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 6442 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-12-12T21:56:26.741673+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-12T21:56:26.741673+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thread_safe (LoadError)
2013-12-12T21:56:26.741673+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-12-12T21:56:26.741673+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:3:in `require'
2013-12-12T21:56:26.741673+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:1:in `require'
```

Comment: Please add the entire output from Heroku that you saw when pushing. This includes information about what gems are being installed and will help others to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add

`gem thread_safe`

to your GemFile and rerun

`bundle`

however, if there are other errors running `heroku logs --tail` for a running log or `heroku logs -n 500` for a specific number of lines, should help to get some more detail

Answer (score 0):

I don't use rails but I had a similar problem with node on heroku - I forgot to save a dependency to my package.json file and heroku didn't know to download it. Seems like you're having that same issue with your active support gem.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, did you add your ruby version to your Gemfile? 
Something like this..

---------    Gemfile   ---------------------------------

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.0.0"

gem list ....
```

make sure you bundle once more, hope that help..